# Pentaho Kettle and Scheduling Tool

Tags: pentaho, scheduling, data-integration

I am using Pentaho Data Integration 5.2 CE and wish to use a scheduling tool with web UI and power to send alerts as mails in case of success or failures.

Please suggest a good open source tool for the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDI comes with it's own [Carte server](https://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/pentaho-data-integration-remote-execution-with-carte/) which allows you to do some monitoring and remote execution. Scheduling can be done with cron and you can then use the carte server to monitor.

If you'd like a nicer Web UI, I can recommend [Azakban](https://azkaban.github.io/), created by the folks at LinkedIn, which i've found to be: easy to setup, very stable, simple for looking at success and failure on transformations or jobs. You basically setup a job file with the executable and upload that to the server. Then you can schedule through it's web ui, as well as look at the results run-time and actually go into the details and review the PDI output logs, which is great.

I've also read good things about Chronos, but haven't tried it as it was a bit more complicated to setup and requieres a Mesos installation.

Comment: Azkaban looks promising. Thanks for your answer. Just tell me one more thing. Is azkaban worth using in Production environment?

Comment: I'm using it in production with an H2 database. You can also use mysql if you like. I'd recommend it.

Comment: Thank you very much Sebastian,